# Make "settings-like" buttons in layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am new to Android dev and kindly asking for help.

I would like to make "settings-like" (full-width, flat, with images, with separators) button in my app. Here is the example:
[Example image from Samsung settings app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx58Y.jpg)

I know about "Preference" view - it is not the solution. Is there any native view for this type of button? If not, what is the most appropriate way to make this button possible?

Upd.: I have managed to make the buttons by myself using LinearLayout. You can find my implementation in answers below.

Comment: use a `ListView`

Comment: there is no view for this type of button. You should design it by yourself using standard views. It is quite easy to do that

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems there is no native view for this type of button in Android.

RecyclerView and ListView will not help, because they require adapters (I have no need in adapters, I need simple buttons only).

So, I decided to make these buttons using linear layout, here is the code:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_sim_card" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/action_edit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Make LinearLayout 
`android:clickable="true"` and 
`android:focusable="true"` 
(later you can just bind onClickListener in code) for it will act like a button. And the main point is to make button-like animations (ink-effect on click) - specify background attribute: 
`android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RecyclerView`. Here's the example of xml:

```
<LinearLayout

    ...>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In Java:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
            linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(this, /*list of your items*/));
```

Than you have to create your own [RecyclerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) class, [ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html) and xml for one single item of the list.